# Trying to read from a file. Throws an exception

Tags: java, swing, file-io, matrix

Im trying to read from a file containing a single vertical file of numbers, and filling a matrix (that is composed by `JTextField`s) with them, but when I try the set method, the program throws an exception after changing to the second row

```
for(int a=0; a < i; a++) { 
    for(int b=0; b < i; b++){
        // x = raf.readLine();
        matrix[a][b].setText(raf.readLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception are you seeing and can you provide a stack trace.

Comment: what is raf? what is i? what is matrix? A little bit more code and/or a stacktrace would be helpful...

Comment: Solved it! The problem was that I was doing raf.close() right after the second "for" finished.

Comment: so, please: either accept one of the answers or provide a valid answer yourself and accept that (or delete the question)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something more like the example below, using some suitable values for `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT`.

```
for (int row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++) {
    for (int col = 0 ; col < WIDTH; col++) {
        matrix[row][col].setText(raf.readLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved it! The problem was that I was doing raf.close() right after the second "for" finished.

Answer (score 2):

You should not read a file from a GUI class. Try separating concerns by creating a dedicated class for reading the text file. Perhaps let your file reader class return an `Iterator<String>` of lines. Now test your file reader class in a unit test and make sure it displays the lines correctly.

Then do something like this:

```
Iterator<String> lines = yourHelperClass.getLines()
for(int a=0; a < i; a++) { 
    for(int b=0; b < i; b++){
        if(!lines.hasNext()){
            // not enough lines, probably throw an Exception here
        }
        matrix[a][b].setText(lines.next());
    }
}
```

That way it will be a lot easier to find out what is actually going wrong.

Recommended read: [Coupling and Cohesion: The Two Cornerstones of OO Programming](http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/coupcoh/)

Comment: +1 Excellent point about cohesion. The dimension metadata should remain near the data itself.

Comment: Solved it! The problem was that I was doing raf.close() right after the second "for" finished.